# JSON decoded data in PHP Array

Tags: php, arrays, json, codeigniter

Trying to access data that has been JSON decoded in PHP, loop through the array and print it in my view, but I keep getting an illegal string offset error for the part of the array I'm trying to access.

When I var-dump the array, I can see the data that has been pulled from the api, but for some reason this error keeps getting thrown when I try to access it. Code below (using codeigniter):

model

```
function getAllPokemon() {
    $url = 'http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?limit=151';
    $response = file_get_contents($url);
    $allPokemonData = json_decode($response, true);
    return $allPokemonData;
}
```

controller

```
public function index()
{
    $data['thepokemon'] = $this->pokemon_model->getAllPokemon();
    $this->load->view('template/header');
        $this->load->view('home', $data);
    $this->load->view('template/footer');
}
```

view

```
<?php foreach($thepokemon as $poke): ?>
    <p><?php echo $poke['name']; ?></p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

If I do something along the lines of:

```
<?php foreach($thepokemon as $poke): ?>
    <p><?php echo $poke[2]['name']; ?></p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

It will print the name for that index in the array, but the error is still thrown.

Any help would be great! Thanks in advance.

example of `var_dump`:

```
array(4) { ["count"]=> int(811) ["previous"]=> NULL ["results"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this:

```
array(4) { 
    ["count"]=> int(811) 
    ["previous"]=> NULL 
    ["results"]=> array(151) { 
        [0]=> array(2) { 
            ["url"]=> string(36) "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1/" 
            ["name"]=> string(9) "bulbasaur" 
        } 
        [1]=> array(2) { 
            ["url"]=> string(36) "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/2/" 
            ["name"]=> string(7) "ivysaur" 
        }
```

So the loop should be:

```
<?php foreach($thepokemon['results'] as $poke): ?>
```

Comment: Thanks dude! I can't believe I missed that - feel like an idiot :)